# Problems with ActionListener and SystemUtil.invokeLater

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have look all over the web, and found no solution to my problem. For a AP Comp Sci project, I am making a Set of games, that will be run from a JFrame with JButtons. I have the games all ready, along with action listeners, but the games dont launch properly. The JFrame and JButtons are all setup correctly too.

```
private static class TetListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        GameCenter.quit();
        GameCenter.startTetris();
    }
}
```

GameCenter.quit() does nothing but run JFrame.dispose(), and GameCenter.startTetris(); constructs a new Tetris object, then run the play() method to start the game. All of Tetris is coded properly and works correctly when it is run in the main method (outside the actionlistener). But as soon as I put it in the ActionListener, it fails to be constructed properly. I tracked the problem down to:

```
public BlockDisplay(BoundedGrid<Block> board)
{
    this.board = board;

    grid = new JPanel[board.getNumRows()][board.getNumCols()];

    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()   // <<<<<<<<<<------------------- Problem Here
    {
        public void run()
        {
            createAndShowGUI();   // <<<<<<<<<<<<-------- Never Run

        }
    });

    //Wait until display has been drawn
    try
    {
        while (frame == null || !frame.isVisible())   // <<<<<<<-------- Never Resolved
        {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

So the program always hangs. I also made a Pacman game that uses this SwingUtilities.invokeLater, so it doesnt work either. I cant figure out why this is happening or how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: does `public BlockDisplay(BoundedGrid<Block> board)` ever get called?

Comment: Yes it does. Tetris works perfectly and as it should when outside the ActionListener.

Answer (score 2):

If the thread that runs `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is already the swing event thread and you run in this while loop, yup, your application will hang.

Get rid of the while loop.

Comment: Ok That fixed Pacman, but Tetris requries that loop to be there, otherwise it begins to though a number of other exceptions. Any ideas?

Comment: your game loop should start if swing is ready to display your GUI. you can register a listener to that effect, check JFrame/Frame class

Comment: Well the exceptions are thrown, because the gui is not ready yet, but the program  is trying to use the components of the gui. So they throw null pointer exceptions.

Comment: can't help you without seeing more sample code and the actual exceptions. Use an event listener that waits for the frame to appear and start your game logic from there

Comment: Ok I will gather more code and the exceptions tomorrow and post them, and give the eventlistener a shot.

Comment: @Jochen
Ok. So the exceptions really arent worth posting, because there are so many of them (different ones) and they all pertain to the fact that the gui isnt there, so the method cannot be run or the object cannot be added to the grid contained within the GUI.

Here is the BlockDisplay Class: http://pastebin.com/s6SVp7pW

Please let me know if you need anything else. I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Well I finally managed to figure it out with some Threading. Thanks for the help.